# Substitute for jQuery Replace

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('img').attr('src').replace('t','c');
```

Since the platform I'm using does not permit the use of replace (it's an undefined method), I'm wondering if there's any other way going about replacing t with c. The original issue was changing all images from this:

```
<img src="http://ourpictures.com/t/1.jpg">
<img src="http://ourpictures.com/t/2.jpg">
etc.
```

To this:

```
<img src="http://ourpictures.com/c/1.jpg">
<img src="http://ourpictures.com/c/2.jpg">
etc.
```

Comment: There is no "jQuery replace". Replace is and always has been a [basic JavaScript string method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). (Besides, the statement *"Vanilla JS is permitted, but not preferred."* is silly.)

Comment: You're going to need to come up with some sort of regex. You don't want to be replacing EVERY "t" with a "c", or your URLs will be "ourpiccures.com".

Comment: If `replace` is undefined, sounds more like `attr('src')` is returning `null`.

Comment: Just to clarify, the t and c aren't replacing anything in ourpcitures.com, the t represents what the parameter would be (e.g. blah_feed_thumb) that needs to get changed to c (e.g. feed_thumb).

Comment: Jquery **is** vanilla js?!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this out, and this worked best:

```
var $els = $('.grid-article__img');

for(var i=0; i<$els.length; i++){

    var $el = $($els[i]);
    //console.log($els[i]);

    if($el.attr('data-original').length>0) {

        var imgSrc = $el.attr('data-original');
        imgSrc = imgSrc.replace(/_cmplx_m/,"");
        $el.attr('data-original', imgSrc);
        $el.attr('src', imgSrc);

    }

}
```